# Mule ESB and Microsoft Service Bus connector

Tags: azure, mule, esb

i have a problem configuring microsoft service bus connector -> when I try to test connection I get exception: Credentials provided are not valid, I am missing something but what?
I have installed Service bus for windows on local machine, created Namespace and tried to connect via SB explorer (standalone test tool) and connection works nice. Connection string that i use to connect looks like this:

**Endpoint=sb://es-ppp02.prd.co.yu/DjurinNamespace;StsEndpoint=https://es-ppp02.prd.co.yu:9355/DjurinNamespace;RuntimePort=9354;ManagementPort=9355**

Now configuring SB connector from mule:
[Mule configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZOQV.png)

Besides Service Namespace and Fully Qualified Domain Name there are two more fields Shared Access Key Name and Shared access key. Following documentation i have found those with Service Bus PowerShell, via command Get-SBAuthorizationRule where I took keyName and primaryKey. I also have imported service bus certificate via JAVA keytool.exe -importcert command.

So if someone have tried and succeeded to connect to Microsoft Service Bus for Windows (not Azure cloud), please tell me what is my mistake?

Regards, Ivan.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved - service bus for windows on premise uses OAuth, so you don't have to configure shared access key (name and key), but instead, username and password (domain username and password) for configured user of service namespace. I was mislead that I have to fill shared access key name and content by tutorial for Microsoft service bus connector.